# How to calculate the background-color of overlapped area of several divs with different translucent background-color?

Tags: css

Say we have two divs partially overlapping each other, of which the one has `background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.3); z-index: 2` and the other `background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.7); z-index: 1`. Now I want to calculate the bgc value of the overlap area.

I performed a test on Chrome 62@MacOS, using the color picker to get the composite color value, ant the result is `rgb(97, 115, 61)`. And I find that if I use opacity instead of the alpha channel of rgba, the value will slightly change to `rgb(98, 117, 63)`. I can figure out neither one.
As I speculate, the red layer should take up 30%, the green one (1-30%)*70=49%, and the white background 21%, so that the result should be `rgb(92, 116, 54)`, where the margin of error seems pretty large?

So why does this happen? Do other browsers behave alike? Is there a spec about it?

[Check the demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/shawtung/9s27kkw7/)

Comment: The divs overlay some background color. Since neither div is fully opaque, the background color will have an input in the calculation of the final value. What color is the underlying background?

Comment: What do you need to calculate this for? Let's try to avoid the XY Problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)